# Weird text artifacts on clients wordpress website

Tags: html, css, wordpress

http://ecc.galengrover.com/programs/facility-rentals/

On that page, and only that page im having a weird issue. Above the content box the words "all areas" appears on top of the other text. The string "All areas" doesn't even exist on the page (it did until i removed it for testing purpose). to make this even weirder this only happens if the text its covering extends to a second line.  any thoughts?

Comment: Elaborating on @MysticEarth's answer: I recommend using Firefox with addons FireBug and WebDeveloper toolbar to analyze scenarios like this. Also, the dithered edges of the text should have given you the clue that there was a jpeg image involved, and right-clicking on it in Firefox yields the option "View background image".

Comment: i use web developer toolbar extensively. not sure how i missed this. ill blame it on how late it was =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your background images.
The image **bg_facility_rentals.jpg** contains "All areas... assigned... are liste..." etc.

Comment: hehe we all have these type of things we sometimes don't see ;)